# How to create popup menu

Tags: javafx-2, popupmenu

I am newbie on javafx. I want to show popup menu on Right Mouse click.  I find one tutorial [Here](http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/popupmenu-in-javafx/)  and [Here](http://lawrencepremkumar.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/custom-specialpopup-using-javafx-2-0/) but don't understand. I want to create popup menu which show in image on this link.

Right now i am creating stage but i don't want stage. I need to show popup menu which show on right click and close when i click anywhere.

Here is my code in which i am using stage but i need to ope popup menu like above link.

```
 public void MouseClickedOnTree(MouseEvent event) {
if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {

        System.out.println("secondary press");
        final Stage optionstage = new Stage();

        VBox vBox = new VBox(5);
        vBox.setMinHeight(50);
        vBox.setMinWidth(50);
        Button btnNewTestBed = new Button("New Testbed");
        btnNewTestBed.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                     optionstage.close();
                    stage.show();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                }
            }
        });
        Button btnOpenTestbed = new Button("Open Testbed");
        btnOpenTestbed.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                optionstage.close();

            }
        });
        optionstage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    System.out.println("click on escape");
                    //Stage sb = (Stage) label.getScene().getWindow();//use any one object
                    if(optionstage.isShowing())
                        optionstage.close();
                }
            }
        });

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(btnNewTestBed, btnOpenTestbed);
        optionstage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 100, 100));
        //stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(new Text(50,50, "my second window")))); 
        optionstage.setX(event.getSceneX());
        optionstage.setY(event.getScreenY());
        optionstage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        optionstage.show();

    }
```

Please provide me any link or reference.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The context of your code is not very clear: is this inside an event handler? If so, what's it an event handler for? If not, what is `event` in the opening `if` statement?

The two links you provide are pretty complex; in JavaFX (unlike Swing) you should only consider subclassing existing Node classes for pretty advanced use cases. You don't need this level of complexity just to create a popup menu.

The easiest way to create a popup menu is for a `Control` (or subclass); you just need to create a `ContextMenu`, add `MenuItem`s to it, and set it as the `contextMenu` on your control:

```
TextField textField = new TextField("Type Something"); // we will add a popup menu to this text field
final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem cut = new MenuItem("Cut");
MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");
MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
contextMenu.getItems().addAll(cut, copy, paste);
cut.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Cut...");
    }
});
// ...
textField.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

If you want to use a `ContextMenu` on a Node that is not a `Control` (a `Pane` or a `Shape`, for example), you don't have a `setContextMenu(...)` method, so you just need a little more work:

```
final AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
// fill pane with nodes, etc
// create context menu and menu items as above
pane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
            contextMenu.show(pane, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
        }
    }
});
```

See the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html) for `ContextMenu` or the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/menu_controls.htm#sthref209) for more details.

Comment: but i want to show it on treeview.   I want to show popup on Treeview when i right click on treeview

Comment: i use this code but popup not showing `contextMenu.show(soariteTree, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());`

Comment: Sorry .. it's working now.... i put declaration code outside event then it;s working... thank you..

Comment: TreeView is a Control, so you can just do 
treeView.setContextMenu(contextMenu); 
No need to register the mouse handler or call show(...)

Comment: There's any example of ResourceBundle in the ContextMenu

Comment: This answer is not the proper solution. The answer by @fuzzyBSc does the trick quite well!

Comment: `ContextMenuEvent` was introduced in JavaFX 2.1; I don't know whether or not this question was posted before 2.1 was released, but note it is specifically tagged javafx-2. For recent versions, the context menu event is the better approach.

Answer (score 16):

James_D already provided a working example consistent with the tutorials but I ran into problems with it. James is correct in saying that for any Node of type Control the correct way to open the context menu is to use [Control.setContextMenu()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setContextMenu(javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu)). However contrary to the tutorial the correct way to register a context menu on non-Control Nodes is as follows (Java 8):

```
    pane.addEventHandler(ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED, event -> {
        contextMenu.show(pane, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
        event.consume();
    });
    pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
        contextMenu.hide();
    });
```

This is consistent with the what setContextMenu does behind the scenes. The setContextMenu implementation for Controls uses and consumes [ContextMenuEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/ContextMenuEvent.html) but does *not* consume the mouse event. This means that if you register a listener for the MouseEvent on a Pane and use setContextMenu on a Control within the Pane a right click on the control will actually open both context menus: The Control will listen for and consume the ContextMenuEvent while the Pane listens for and consumes the MouseEvent. I found in my code with openjdk-8 that registering a ContextMenuEvent listener on the Pane solved this duplicate context menu problem.

I also found that a menu registered on a Pane does not dismiss by default when the user clicks elsewhere. The MOUSE_PRESSED listener that does not consume its event ensures the menu is dismissed when it should be.

Comment: there is also a setOnContextMenuRequested() method in Node

Comment: @Andrew actually many times will require this and the second part of fuzzyBsc's answer.

Answer (score 1):

James_D's higher up answer is wrong. If you right click on that non-control pane, but click away, the context menu doesn't autohide.

I like fuzzyBSc's answer, but I've found this combination to work in all edge cases:

```
pane.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> contextMenu.show(pane, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()));
pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> contextMenu.hide());
```