# adding context menu to pane in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

i'am trying to make context menu that will show when i click right mouse click 
but it's look like i just can add the context menu to the controls only 
here is me code

```
MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");
MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
MenuItem cut = new MenuItem("Cut");
                
edit.getItems().addAll(copy,paste,cut);
                
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                
contextMenu.getItems().addAll(copy,cut,paste);
                
pane.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
        System.out.println("asasasa");
        contextMenu.show(pane, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
    } else {
        contextMenu.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635192/how-to-create-popup-menu) seems to add a `ContentMenu` to a `Panel`

Comment: i already tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Then proved a full runnable example which demonstrates your issues